# How to add custom field attribute in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo

I want to add some custom attributes to the field label of xml, such as:

```
 <group>
   field name="a" custom="value"/>
 </group>
```

custom="value" is my custom label.

But it seems that odoo will erase the label it can not recognise.

How to add it?

Comment: I want it to be converted to: <td data-field="hello-field" class="hello-class" custom="value">hello world</td>

Answer (score 1):

Try with `string` attribute of field tag.

For example:

```
<field name="a" string="Custom Label">
```

[All attributes of field tag.](http://openerp-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/03_module_dev_03.html#field)

Comment: Does not work for me. I tried to add string label but the field was converted to <td data-field="hello-field" custom="hello-class">hello world</td>, and string label was erased.

Answer (score 0):

For add a label in xml file :

```
<label for="a"/>
```

But for displaying "Custom Label", modifie in python file :

```
'a': fields.char('Custom Label', size=64, required=True),
```

Comment: you can also modify the label of a field from the `xml` view by setting the string attribute, look at @odedra's answer

Comment: Sorry, what I want is <td data-field="hello-field" custom="hello-class">hello world</td>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `label` tag, like this

`<label for='a' string='custom label'></label>`

`<field name="a"/>`

This will work.